# Get width from responsive React element during first render?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component named `ResultList` that is responsible for displaying products in a gallery.

But in order to choose the correct quantitity of products per row, I need to know how many pixels were left for my component, because there is some other logic that will determine if a side bar and a filter bar will appear together with the `ResultList` or not. Hence, the **width** of `ResultList` is responsive and it varies.

I've built this code to get the width of the element, but right now it doesn't work for the first render. And I don't know if that would be possible, because the element hasn't been created yet and the `ref` has not been assigned to anything. But how can I choose how many products to display on first render if I'm not able to know how wide my element is going to be?

**See GIF below:**

my `ResultList` would be the `Item2`

[image]

**QUESTION**

How can I get the width of `Item2` during first render, and if that's not possible how can I hide it until I know what is the available width for it? Is there a better way to get the width of a responsive element than with `window.getComputedStyle` ?

**CodeSandbox Link:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-blackburn-f1p7j

**Full Code:**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const S = {};

S.Container_DIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
`;

S.FlexItem1 = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
`;

S.FlexItem2 = styled.div`
  flex: 1 1 80%;
  background-color: lightcoral;
`;

S.FlexItem3 = styled.div`
  flex: 0 0 160px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
`;

function App() {
  const itemRef = useRef(null);
  const [boolean, setBoolean] = useState(false);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <S.Container_DIV>
        <S.FlexItem1>Item 1</S.FlexItem1>
        <S.FlexItem2 ref={itemRef}>Item 2</S.FlexItem2>
        <S.FlexItem3>Item 3</S.FlexItem3>
      </S.Container_DIV>
      <div>
        <br />
        Item2 width is:{" "}
        {itemRef.current && window.getComputedStyle(itemRef.current).width}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setBoolean(prevState => !prevState)}>
          Force Update
        </button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To wait until the elements have rendered and thus the ref has a value you'll need to use an effect. useEffect kind of works, but you'll see a flicker of it rendering once before you recalculate. Instead, this is a case where [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) can be used. It will render once, then you do your measurement and set state, then it will *synchronously* render again so no flicker should be seen.

```
function App() {
  const itemRef = useRef(null);
  const [itemWidth, setItemWidth] = useState(-1);
  const [boolean, setBoolean] = useState(false);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
   // I don't think it can be null at this point, but better safe than sorry
    if (itemRef.current) {
       setItemWidth(window.getComputedStyle(itemRef.current).width);
    }
  });
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <S.Container_DIV>
        <S.FlexItem1>Item 1</S.FlexItem1>
        <S.FlexItem2 ref={itemRef}>Item 2</S.FlexItem2>
        <S.FlexItem3>Item 3</S.FlexItem3>
      </S.Container_DIV>
      <div>
        <br />
        Item2 width is: {itemWidth}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setBoolean(prevState => !prevState)}>
          Force Update
        </button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

---

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(itemRef.current).width` returns value with "px".